# How can I change result per page in Google Custom Search with query parameters?

Tags: google-custom-search

I need to implement site search system with Google Custom Search or Google Site Search.

(Now I use Custom Search on Local, But I use Site Search when production server worked)

I must implement change result per page program.

I think that could do with query parameters like this.

```
<div>
<a href="/result?q=test&num=10">10</a>
<a href="/result?q=test&num=20">20</a>
<a href="/result?q=test&num=30">30</a>
</div>
```

But result per page always bring me back just 10 per page.

Anyone know ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's able to do like this.

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];
$num = $_GET['num'];
if(empty($num)){
    $num = 10;
}
?>

<div id="gsc">
    <script>
      (function() {
        var cx = '(My API Key)';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
        gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
      })();
   </script>
   <gcse:searchbox-only resultsUrl="?num=<?php echo $num; ?>" filtered_cse=1></gcse:searchbox-only>
</div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="?num=10&q=<?php echo $q; ?>">10</a></li>
    <li><a href="?num=20&q=<?php echo $q; ?>">20</a></li>
    <li><a href="?num=30&q=<?php echo $q; ?>">30</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="results">
    <gcse:searchresults-only webSearchResultSetSize="<?php echo $num; ?>"></gcse:searchresults-only>
</div>
```